# Uninstalling Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-media-player

I installed Windows 7 Ultimate N on my laptop which I got from MSDN. The N version of windows comes with no media software preinstalled which is fine by me but I need it just one time so I installed update Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N and Windows 7 KN (KB968211). When I did what I wanted I tried to remove that update from List of installed updates but there were no such option. I left it there but than I noticed my boot time was multiplied by 3 time (before 20-30 seconds to full desktop, after 1 minute and 30 seconds to full desktop; I have a software which monitor booting process). I didn't install any new software other than that update so I'm pretty sure it's because of media pack. Since I can't remove it from control panel I tried with removing it from CMD (Run it as administrator) with:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:968211
```

Sadly this didn't work either. Does anyone have any other suggestions how could I do it?

Comment: You should ask why Windows boots slowly ;) Run a xbootmgr boot trace, to see what is slow: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140247-trace-windows-7-bootshutdownhibernatestandbyresume-issues/

Comment: And the Feature Pack isn't in the List of installed _programs_ either? You could also try unchecking **Media Features** in **Turn Windows features on or off**. Or a system restore if you really want to get rid of it.

Comment: I already turned off in Windows features, It's not in the list of installed programs, only in list of installed updates where is not removable. I guess I'll make fresh install.

Comment: Just to clarify: with system restore, I meant the built-in Windows functionality to roll back the system to an earlier state (and not a fresh install).

Comment: FWIW, by turning the "Media Features" off in the "Turn Windows features on or off" dialog, I did get rid of the DVD Maker, Movie Player and Media Center, with the added benefit that now video thumbnails are generated, so I suppose that's a state I can live with :)